# How can I change string inside a function?

Tags: shell

I am writing a function

```
func-def.sh:

function func() {
    # assign _f_desc here ....
}


run-main.sh :


function call_all_func() {
    source func-def.sh
    # when I call the function from here
    _f_desc= 
    func _f_desc
    # here I must get the function description of the function
    # that was last executed ... 
}
```

In short I want to pass `_f_desc` to `func()` and expecting `func()` to fill in a short string describing it's usage .. for ex. `_f_desc` might contain `"This function multiplies 2 nos"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly pass a variable to be able to change it. See script below:

```
function call_all_func() {
   local _f_desc
   func
   echo "$_f_desc"
}

function func() {
   _f_desc="This function multiplies 2 nos"
}
```

Now call:

```
call_all_func
```

It will print:

```
This function multiplies 2 nos
```